# Subversion in a single picture

Tags: svn, mercurial

Does anybody know good illustration for basic [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) usage? Something like images in this directory: http://www.ivy.fr/mercurial/ref/v1.0/ (they are for [Mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/)), single image illustrating most common actions.

Answer (score 7):

That one is more detailed (From [Subversion (svn) quickstart](http://agata.in2p3.fr/dotclear/index.php?2005/05/13/6-subversion-svn-quickstart)):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A good one about **branching** from "[Subversion branching in my experience](http://www.javalinux.it/wordpress/?p=32)"

[image: svn]

Answer (score 3):

My own picture, inspired by Mercurial one (click on it to see bigger image):

[alt text http://stuff.wfrag.org/tracpy/browser/quicksvn/Subversion-QuickStart-v1.0-60-dpi.png?format=raw](http://stuff.wfrag.org/tracpy/wiki/QuickSVN)

Answer (score 2):

[Humor ON] (i.e. wiki-owned answer)

That one is about a very important subject - [publication of data](http://www.nixonmcinnes.co.uk/2007/11/28/publication-one-project-multiple-developers-part-2/) into production -...
and must be also one of the ugliest schema I ever saw on SVN ;)

Still, it is a topic to consider, even for a single developer, as this [other SO question illustrates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330848).

[image: svn]

Comment: You're missing the wooden table! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Another [good introduction](http://aji.techshu.com/svn/):

[image]
<sub>(source: [idealwebtools.com](http://img.idealwebtools.com/blog/svn.gif))</sub>