# Any reasons to switch from SVN for a one-man linear Django project that's virtualenv isolated?

Tags: python, django, svn, version-control, virtualenv

I see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330848/best-version-control-for-a-one-man-web-app) but it's from 2008. Seems like many version control systems have become trendy lately. Also, the question was **exactly** my situation:

- Django based web application
- Using an [isolated virtulaenv environment](http://www.travisswicegood.com/2010/01/17/django-virtualenv-pip-and-fabric/)
- One man developer
- Will not be open sourced
- Linear project (no branches)
- Perhaps will be using tags for releases (but not needed)

At some point, it might become two developers. I'll worry about that down the line.

**My question:** Is there any reason to switch to another version control system now? I use [SVN](http://subversion.tigris.org/) on a Linux development box right now.

Comment: If you're not using branches and there's only one of you I think any VCS is equivalent to running regular backups of your work.

Comment: Thanks @katrielalex. Perhaps I should just delete this question. I am comfortable with VCS but was curious if maybe I'm missing out on something.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that just because there's only one of you doesn't mean branching is a bad idea! It's often convenient to want to try something in your main branch without breaking it, or to develop several different things at once without having to worry about one of them breaking the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a one-person development effort, use whatever version control system lets you get your work down most effectively. For my own private projects, I do use Git these days, but that's only because I feel it gives me benefits vs. other choices. It is really up to personal preference.

Lately I've felt like I should also learn Mercurial, to be more well rounded, but that's just for my own education. So again, whatever works best for you is what to use.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: What are the benefits you see in using Git?

Comment: Because I can easily branch and merge with Git, I can work outside of master, see if an idea is useful, and easily discard it if not. SVN 1.6.x has better branching support than 1.4.x, which was the last major version I used full time, so it's possible 1.6.x also has some of these benefits. Also: Git is "faster" for some operations, and doesn't spew .svn into every folder.

Comment: You know, honestly, I always forget about programmers.stackexchange.com . Making a note of that for my next questions. Sorry.